# Certificate transparency monitoring

Tags: certificates

Does exists monitoring for certificate transparency logs ?

For example, a web service how send you an email each time a new certificate for a specific domain is seen in a CT log ?

Comment: Service recommendations are beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for service recommandations, but thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: There is now that open source tool: https://github.com/SSLMate/certspotter